# How to do endless loading in iphone app like facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, tableview

Is there any way to do like Facebook loading that i have one array having 100 objects and on screen 10 cell display.what i want is when i scroll want loading at footer and another 10 data should come and so on...i tried too much but couldn't find this. Data is come from WebService and i am taking it to an array.

Also is this possible that when i scroll and goes to bottom of the tableview it automatically display 10 new cell without reload all table.

I tried this but not success

```
 if (indexPath.row == [newsArray count] - 1)
            [self News_WS_Called];
```

please help i tried a lot and now i feel like tired.

Comment: May be you are looking something like this http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Answer (score 0):

try this..

`UItableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.so by using scroll view delegate method..

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height == scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"add rows");
        // call your method to add rows
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: i got it but please explain what will be the method for call rows?

Comment: how you populating your tableView?